# Accessing Page datafolder data from C#

Tags: user-controls, c1-cms

I defined a Page datafolder in the Data view and created data for one of my pages.

How can I access this data from an ASP.NET usercontrol placed on the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a small code sample for getting page folder data for a given page folder type. Change the type Martin.MyPageFolder to your type and it should work just fine.

```
using (DataConnection connection = new DataConnection())
{
  var pageFolderData = 
    from d in connection.Get<Martin.MyPageFolder>()
    where d.PageId == SitemapNavigator.CurrentPageId
    select d;

  foreach (var item in pageFolderData)
  {
    // Use the item here as you need
  }             
}
```

Comment: The custom type is not recognised in VS, probably because I am running C1 as a WebApplication and the generated files are not automatically included in the project. Where does the type get saved to?

Comment: The type should exist in the Composite.Generated.dll. What version of C1 are you running?

Comment: I was missing a reference to this dll. Now it works, thanks a lot!